# Wordpress homepage infinite redirect

Tags: php, redirect

My word press site http://octechservices.org has a homepage that keeps redirecting. Just the homepage does this, and I can't figure out why. I believe the redirects are being generated by the canonical.php file, but I cannot figure out why, or how to fix it. The site redirect from the http://octechservices.org/ to that exact same url. I am using the wordpress default .htaccess file. Do you have any suggestions for solving this problem?
Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The problem is caused by the permalink settings. The site loops when the permalinks are changed away from plain. Also, this only happens outside my lan.

Comment: I can see that your site 301 redirects endlessly. Without more information like what you have done to get stuck like this (and/or what you have tried to get unstuck) I'm working in the dark. Can you add anything else you think might be at all relevant?